# Path in client-server application to file transfer JAVA

Tags: java, path, ftp, client-server

I have problem with my application server-client to file transfer in java.

In client side I choose path to file by FileDialog and send to server but I don't know how can I set path in server side.

Which will be path for this sending file?

Client side:

```
try {

            FileDialog fd =new FileDialog(this,"Select",FileDialog.LOAD);
             fd.setVisible(true);
             String katalog=fd.getDirectory();
             String plik=fd.getFile();
             pw.println(plik);
             infoPlik2.setText(plik);
             jta.setText("");
             jta.append("File: " + plik);
             jta.append("in directory: "+ katalog);

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(plik);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytes = 0;
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            while ((bytes = fis.read(buffer)) >0) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, bytes);
            }
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            double kbps = (double) bytes / (end - start);
            sFile2.setText("Speed: " + kbps + " kbps");
            fis.close();
        } catch (Exception exx) {
            System.out.println(exx.getMessage());
        }
```

Server side:
try {

```
            //File f = new File() ???????????????
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
        BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int count;
        InputStream ins = incoming.getInputStream();
        while ((count = ins.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            fos.write(buffer);
        }
        fos.close();
        incoming.close();
```

Something like that, please help me how can I resolve this problem.

Comment: It's your task, we can't know what the specifications are. You have to decide what you want to save exactly and where.

Answer (score 0):

Your code only transfers content.
what you lack is transfering file name/path. Send it before or after.